# What are limitations of Kirchhoff laws in presence of A..C current.what are the bounds on its application in such case?

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis, basic

I'm not able to understand while Kirchhoff's laws seem to be based on very fundamental logic they are still not applicable in some cases.
I tried to look for answer in text book but got no clear view. On internet too I heaven't got very clear presentation but only lines such as
"They are accurate for DC circuits, and for AC circuits at frequencies where the wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation are very large compared to the circuits."
Please clarify my doubt.

Comment: Do you understand how an antenna works?

Comment: no till now i have had no course on antenna. So i don't fully know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kirchhoff's laws are applicable if the [*lumped element model*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped_element_model#Electrical_systems) of your circuit is valid, i.e. if you can assume that \$\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}\$ and \$\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}\$ are zero or neglectible **outside** all of your circuit elements (they may be non-zero **inside** the lumped elements like inductors or capacitors).

Kirchhoffs's laws are not valid, e.g. if you have to consider induction in one of your circuit loops or displacement currents into/out of your circuit nodes.
This is the case e.g. in antennas (as Ignacio pointed out) or inside parts of  some lumped circuit elements (inductors, capacitors).

Comment: so does this mean Kirchhoff's laws are ineffective in cases where E.M waves are employed. and when ckt. elements deviate from ideal behavior

Comment: "where E.M. waves are employed" is a very general expression. If you mean where E.M. waves induce voltage in circuit loops or cause currents into circuit nodes, then yes, then Kirchhoff's laws aren't valid any more and you have to go back to Maxwell's Equations (continuous E/M-fields and PDEs instead of discrete number of currents/voltages and system of ODEs)

Comment: ok so now it adds up "They are accurate for DC circuits, and for AC circuits at frequencies where the wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation are very large compared to the circuits."essentially means a specified limiting condition for the type of em wave employed in the ckt. Plz. tell if i got it correct now. thanks

Comment: No. Actually the wavelength condition is neither neccessary nor sufficient for KCL and KVL to be valid. E.g. you can have a so called ground loop in a small circuit where an AC voltage of 50Hz (huge wavelength) is induced (=violation of KVL). On the other hand you can rely on KVL and KCL even for large microwave circuits. In the latter case you may have to use *distributed element model* (e.g. model connections as transmission lines instead of ordinary connection) instead of *lumped element model* but KVL and KCL may still be valid.

Comment: so can u plz. explain me the physical significance of this condition so that i have clear knowledge of the basics.

Comment: The condition "circuit size << wavelength" just makes it easier to work with (you can use *lumped element model* instead of *distributed element model*). I would see this, however, completely independent of the other conditions (\$\dot B=0\$, \$\dot q=0\$). Only the latter ones are necessary and sufficient for KVL and KCL.